# Is an unequal relationship preserved from limits?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Consider three real numbers, $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

What I want to prove is $ab-c\neq 0$.

For now, I derived the following condition: $\forall \delta \in \mathbb{R}\backslash${$0,1$}, $a(b/\delta)-c\neq 0.$

And, I considered a proof:
$\textrm{Fix a sequence } \delta_n\subset \mathbb{R}\backslash${$0,1$}$\textrm{ such that }\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\delta_n=1, \textrm{ then } (a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq 0 \textrm{ and }\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}0,\textrm{ thus }ab-c\neq 0.$

However, I think, $(a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}0$ does not hold without additional assumptions.

So, does $(a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a(b/\delta_n)-c)\neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}0$ hold? If doesn't, what assumption is needed?

Comment: Short answer: NO WAY.

Comment: Somewhat longer answer: For all $n$ we have $1/n\ne0$, yet $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$.

Comment: If for every $\delta$ other than $1$ and $0$ you have $a(b/\delta)\neq c$, then because $\delta=ba/c$ would give you equality, you either have that $c=0$ (so this doesn't make sense), or $b=0$ or $a=0$ (so $\delta=0$), or else $ab=c$. In particular you'll be able to prove your claim exactly when what you want does **not** happen.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.